# Intersection of char that go in a row

Tags: intersection

I need to find the longest match with the entered words or numbers which go in a row.
For example:

```
132 12332 12312 = 1
ABCDEFGH ABCDEFG ABCEDF ABCED = ABC
ABCDEFGH ABCDEFG ABCEDF ABCED = ABC
ABCDEFGH ABCDEFG ABCDEF ABCDE = ABCDE
ABCDEFGH ABCDEFG ABCDEF ABCDE EDCBA = A
ABCDEFGH ABCDEFG ABCDEF ABCDE EDCBCA = BC
ABCDEFGH ABCDEFG AxBCDEF ABCDxE EDCBCAABCD = BCD
ABCDEFGH 1234 = 
ABCDEFGH = ABCDEFGH
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't shared a code snippet, I'm going to try and give a possible approach to you rather than a code.

You can first look for the shortest string in the set of strings entered. Next, you can check for a possibility that that very string is present as a substring in all the other strings. If all pass it, then that's your answer.

If any string fails, you have to figure out what part of your shortest string still matches with the failed string and recheck.

This might be Brute Force and pretty exhaustive, but it will lead you to the answer you are looking for.